# ConcurrentModificationException in Android AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask, concurrentmodification

I have a strange issue, which I'm hoping I can explain well enough. My app has two activities - MainActivity and SearchActivity. I have a button on MainActivity which triggers an upload from the database on the device to a remote database on my web server. If I click the button when I first launch the app, no problem, works fine. If I switch to the SearchActivity, don't do anything, and switch back, then try the button, the app crashes with a ConcurrentModificationException.
I've got an AsyncTask which sends the contents of a local database (already pulled out of the database and sent to the thread through the parameters as an ArrayList). I've spent hours debugging this and still can't work out where it is. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code triggered on the button press, to request the contents of the database from a separate Databaser thread

```
Button btnRemoteSync = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSync);
    btnRemoteSync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent startUpload = new Intent(getString(R.string.broadcast_search_database));
            startUpload.putExtra("type-id",1);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(startUpload);
        }
    });
```

This is the code in the BroadcastReceiver which gets each response from the databaser and adds them to an ArrayList of custom ResponseObjects. When the databaser thread sends a bssid value of DONE, the AsyncTask is launched with the ArrayList passed in as a parameter.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String bssid = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.data_bssid));
       if (bssid.equals("DONE")) {
            RemoteDatabaseUploader rdb = new RemoteDatabaseUploader(getApplicationContext());
            rdb.execute(databases);
       } else {
           databases.add(new ResponseObject(getApplicationContext(),
                   bssid,
                   intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.data_ssid)),
                   intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.data_capabilities)),
                   intent.getIntExtra(getString(R.string.data_level), 0),
                   intent.getIntExtra(getString(R.string.data_frequency), 0),
                   intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.data_timestamp)),
                   intent.getDoubleExtra(getString(R.string.data_latitude), 0),
                   intent.getDoubleExtra(getString(R.string.data_longitude), 0)));

       }
    }
```

Below is the doInBackground code for the AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(ArrayList<ResponseObject>... params) {
    ArrayList<ResponseObject> entries = params[0];
    try {
        URL url = new URL(insertURL);
        for (Iterator<ResponseObject> it = entries.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            ResponseObject ro = it.next(); // THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION REFERENCES IN THE DEBUG OUTPUT
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            String postParams = "bssid=" + ro.BSSID
                    + "&ssid=" + ro.SSID
                    + "&capabilities=" + ro.CAPABILITIES
                    + "&level=" + String.valueOf(ro.LEVEL)
                    + "&frequency=" + String.valueOf(ro.FREQUENCY)
                    + "&timestamp=" + ro.TIMESTAMP
                    + "&lat=" + String.valueOf(ro.LAT)
                    + "&long=" + String.valueOf(ro.LON);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(postParams);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            Log.d("RemoteDatabase : ", "Post sent " + ro.BSSID + " || " + String.valueOf(urlConnection.getResponseCode()));
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    entries.clear();

    return null;
}
```

---

EDIT -- I appear to have traced the issue down to another section of code, where a broadcast is sent on clicking the button. The button definitely only sends once (been checking using Log.d) but the received in the databaser is receiving it twice. Trying to fix this now.

Comment: Do you know what a `ConcurrentModificationException` is? Do you know why it might be a problem to add an element to a list in one thread while you are iterating it in another thread?

Comment: @AndyTurner I do know what that error is, but I shouldn't be modifying it in one thread and iterating in another - the iteration should only begin once the Databaser sends "Done" to the main thread, meaning the list is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while but realised I forgot to add how I solved this, just in case it is a help to anyone else.

I found the issue here was actually that some Android devices send multiple copies of a broadcast. I was using an HTC handset for testing and apparently for some reason they send 2 copies of all broadcasts. The way my code was working I was spawning a thread off a broadcast, which was resulting in 2 identical threads operating on the same data. When these completed they were each sending their "Done" broadcast, which was resulting in 4 of them being received by the main thread. Complete mess. 
I ended up having to add a unique ID token to each broadcast and record the values at the receiving end, so if the same ID was received twice no action would be taken the second time.

Answer (score 1):

Please insert a progress bar in your onPreExecute() method of async task and dismiss it in onPostExecute().I thing it is taking too much time to complete the async task,and you are tapping the button again prior to the completion of the async task.

Comment: The exception happens pretty much the instant I press it the first time. I've been careful not to press it twice for that exact reason. I probably should include a progress bar anyway, but I hadn't bothered since this is just for uni coursework on network programming. Technically I don't need to fix this error since the networking part works if I do it at the right time, but it's irritating the hell out of me

Comment: I guess,you tapped the button after coming back from the searchActivity?How can we ensure that the previous asynchronous task has been completed or not.So to avoid user action till the completion of the async task we normally uses progress bar.

Comment: Yeah but there shouldn't be another instance of the AsyncTask created before the button is pressed (in fact I know there isn't as I've been checking using Log.d). I've just put an edit onto the original post - I think I've nearly tracked the issue down. BroadcastReceiver for the database request seems to be detected twice despite being sent once